# impossible IE7 Z-Index, nested element bug!

Tags: css, list, internet-explorer-7, nested, z-index

http://ec4u.dev.creative-ctrl.com/product/wallys-natural-100-beeswax-ear-candles-12pk

Check it.

cannot get .menu ul to render for the life of me!!

strange enough, it renders in ie6, ie8, safari, and ff, but not ie7! I've tried everything. Any ideas?

(I'm pretty close to xhtml strict validation too).

Comment: Earwax Candle..... Why would you juxtapose the word 'ear' when you're trying to sell a beeswax candle?

Comment: @Tyler - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ear_candling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks it's the IE7 CSS (themes/EC4U/ie7.css) that is responsible.  Simply removing those styles was enough for the menu to show up for me.

Comment: Right on man, it's often the simplest of mistakes like that. Problem solved.